Kähler metric expression in normal coordinate
I am reading comparison geometry of holomorphic bisectional curvature for Kähler manifolds and limit spaces by John Lott. I'm confused when reading the following statement:

Let $M$ be a complete Kähler manifold. In complex normal coordinates around $p$, the metric is
$$g_{i\bar j}=\delta_{ij}-\frac12R_{i\bar jk\bar l}z^k\bar z^l+o(|z|^2).$$

By the definition of normal coordinates,
$$g_{i\bar j}(p)=\delta_{ij},\quad\frac{\partial g_{i\bar j}}{\partial z^k}(p)=0=\frac{\partial g_{i\bar j}}{\partial\bar z^k}(p).$$
So the $0$-th order term and the $1$-st order terms are correct.
\begin{align*}
R_{i\bar jk\bar l}&=\langle\nabla_{Z_i}\nabla_{\overline Z_j}Z_k-\nabla_{\overline Z_j}\nabla_{Z_i}Z_k-\nabla_{[Z_i,\overline Z_j]}Z_k,\overline Z_l\rangle\\
&=\langle-\nabla_{\overline Z_j}(\Gamma_{ik}^\alpha Z_\alpha),\overline Z_l\rangle\\
&=-g_{\alpha\bar l}\frac{\partial\Gamma_{ik}^\alpha}{\partial\bar z^j}\\
&=-g_{\alpha\bar l}\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z^j}\left(g^{\bar\beta\alpha}\frac{\partial g_{k\bar\beta}}{\partial z^i}\right)\\
&=-g_{\alpha\bar l}\frac{\partial g^{\bar\beta\alpha}}{\partial\bar z^j}\frac{\partial g_{k\bar\beta}}{\partial z^i}-g_{\alpha\bar l}g^{\bar\beta\alpha}\frac{\partial^2g_{k\bar\beta}}{\partial z^i\partial\bar z^j}.
\end{align*}
Therefore in normal coordinate,
$$R_{i\bar jk\bar l}(p)=-\frac{\partial^2g_{k\bar l}}{\partial z^i\partial\bar z^j}(p)=-\frac{\partial^2g_{i\bar j}}{\partial z^k\partial\bar z^l}(p).$$
But I couldn't get $\dfrac{\partial^2g_{i\bar j}}{\partial z^k\partial z^l}(p)=0$ and $\dfrac{\partial^2g_{i\bar j}}{\partial\bar z^k\partial\bar z^l}(p)=0$. Perhaps the Taylor expansion of several complex variables function I think is not correct?
Let $f$ be a smooth function in $\mathbb C^n$, i.e. $f$ has any order of derivative but not necessarily holomorphic. At $z=0$, I think the Taylor expansion of $f$ is:
\begin{align*}
f(z_1,\cdots,z_n)&=f(0)+\left(\sum_i\left.z_i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\right|_{z=0}+\sum_i\left.\bar z_i\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z_i}\right|_{z=0}\right)f\\
&\quad+\frac1{2!}\left(\sum_i\left.z_i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\right|_{z=0}+\sum_i\left.\bar z_i\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z_i}\right|_{z=0}\right)^2f\\
&\quad+\cdots\cdots\\
&\quad+\frac1{n!}\left(\sum_i\left.z_i\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}\right|_{z=0}+\sum_i\left.\bar z_i\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar z_i}\right|_{z=0}\right)^nf\\
&\quad+o(|z|^n),
\end{align*}
where $\left(x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)^2f$ means $x^2\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+2xy\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}+y^2\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$. Any help would be appreciated!

Lott's statement is not quite correct. It is not true that the stated expansion holds for all holomorphic normal coordinates system. What is true is that there always exists one such coordinate system where the expansion holds. These are called "Bochner coordinates" or "K-coordinates". You can just search these terms on the internet to find references with the statement and proof. Often-cited references about this include Tian's ETH lecture notes, Kontsevich's 1995 Bourbaki, and Bochner's Bull AMS paper in 1947.

@YangMills Thank you for including these references. It's very helpful!
